# Fcntl in go doesn't work

Tags: go, file-locking

I'm currently writing a http server, that has to run over all files inside a folder. One Request can write a file, where another Request can read the files at the same time, so i need to lock the file, that is open for writing. In the Routine, that will read the file, i just want to skip the file that is locked.
To make this, i want to use locklibrarys like that from [rubyist](https://github.com/rubyist/lockfile) or [nightlyone](https://github.com/nightlyone/lockfile).

The problem is, i didnt get them to work, so i started to call the syscall.FcntlFlock() function myself and it didn't work like i had expected.
This program doesn't work in the Go Playground, cause the playground seems to run not on a unix-based system (syscall.FcntlFlock is undefined)

The code that didn't work:

```
func main() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    file, err := os.Open("lockfiletest.lock")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error opening file2: %s", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    flockT := syscall.Flock_t{
        Type: syscall.F_WRLCK,
        Whence: io.SeekStart,
        Start: 0,
        Len: 0,
    }
    err = syscall.FcntlFlock(file.Fd(), syscall.F_SETLK, &flockT)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error locking file2: %s", err)
        return
    }

    log.Println("lock2 accessed")

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)

    log.Println("func2 finished")

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 15)
}
```

the console output:

```
2017/10/28 00:18:12 error locking file2: bad file descriptor
Process finished with exit code 0
```

What am i doing wrong? Are the syscalls broken?
I also tried it in C and there it works fine.
I test this program in Go1.8.3 and Go1.9.1 on ubuntu16.04

PS: This program also have to run on windows, so only implementing a FcntlLock isn't enough.

---

I also thoght about using sync.RWMutex, so it is locked via a Mutex instead of a fileLock. That is not exactly what i want, cause i only want to skip the file that is locked and not wait until the mutex can be locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I create the file with `touch lockfiletest.lock`, that is with no file contents, your program fails with your error: `error locking file2: bad file descriptor`.

```
$ rm -f lockfiletest.lock
$ touch lockfiletest.lock
$ go run lockfiletest.go
2017/10/27 21:17:27 error locking file2: bad file descriptor
```

I changed the file open to closely match `TestFcntlFlock`.

```
$ uname -s
Linux
~/go/src/syscall$ $ go test -v -run=TestFcntlFlock syscall_unix_test.go
=== RUN   TestFcntlFlock
--- PASS: TestFcntlFlock (0.01s)
PASS
ok      syscall 0.008s
~/go/src/syscall$
```

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    name := "lockfiletest.lock"
    file, err := os.OpenFile(name, syscall.O_CREAT|syscall.O_RDWR|syscall.O_CLOEXEC, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error opening file: %s", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    flockT := syscall.Flock_t{
        Type:   syscall.F_WRLCK,
        Whence: io.SeekStart,
        Start:  0,
        Len:    0,
    }
    err = syscall.FcntlFlock(file.Fd(), syscall.F_SETLK, &flockT)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error locking file: %s", err)
        return
    }

    log.Println("lock2 accessed")

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)

    log.Println("func2 finished")

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 15)
}
```

Output:

```
$ rm -f lockfiletest.lock
$ touch lockfiletest.lock
$ go run lockfiletest.go
2017/10/27 21:21:56 lock2 accessed
2017/10/27 21:22:01 func2 finished
$ rm -f lockfiletest.lock
$ go run lockfiletest.go
2017/10/27 21:22:25 lock2 accessed
2017/10/27 21:22:30 func2 finished
$ go run lockfiletest.go
2017/10/27 21:25:40 lock2 accessed
2017/10/27 21:25:45 func2 finished
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to open your file WRONLY or RDWR, you're opening it read only to put a lock on it which doesn't work - you're getting a read only file descriptor.